# Switching from Wifi to mobile data takes long time

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-moto-g, mobile-data

Since a few weeks ago, my Moto G takes a long time to start up mobile data after I turn off wifi. Usually it will take only a few seconds, but now it can take 10 minutes or even more. As long as it stays on, there is absolutely no problem with the mobile data. The problem only arises when I use wifi, then turn it off to get back to mobile data.